# Bash scripts extremely slow to start on OSX

Tags: bash, macos

I'm having a problem where my bash scripts take an extremely long time to start.  At first I thought that it was something in the script itself, but a quick experiment disproved that.

This is the example script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'ping'
```

When I run it

```
$ time ./script.sh
```

I get

```
ping

real    0m12.018s
user    0m0.002s
sys    0m0.002s
```

(I've even seen it go up to 17 seconds...) What's incredibly strange is that when I run it *the second time*, it goes instantly.

```
ping

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s
```

But when I edit the file again, it's back to the long wait.

```
$ echo 'echo test' >> gbr.sh
$ time ./gbr.sh
ping
test

real    0m13.021s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.003s
```

It's almost like bash is compiling my script or something.  *Is there any way to debug this?*  It also doesn't seem to be anything with my `.bash_profile` - if I just put an echo on the first line of `.bash_profile` I still only see that after 10+ seconds.

I've tried this in iTerm2 and in native Terminal - both have exactly the same issue.  This is on macOS Sierra - 10.12.3

Comment: dtrace is the tool I'd reach for here. Actually, dtruss will probably suffice.

Comment: (no, there isn't any compilation process. Yes, there *can* be scripts that run themselves even on noninteractive shell startup, but the normal/documented way to do that is to put the name of such a script in the environment variable `BASH_ENV`, so if that isn't set, then you don't have something hooking in the documented/proper way).

Comment: ...incidentally, by the way, this smells to me much like an antimalware / system-monitoring product doing its thing (ie. calculating a hash of your script, sending that hash off to a remote service and getting an answer back). If that's so, you should see the same behavior not just with bash, but with *any* interpreted scripts -- a script starting with `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`, etc.

Comment: How long does `time bash -c exit` take?

Comment: Maybe your system is having a delay while retrieving the `ping` binary path for some reason. I've seen that behavior in macOS before. Try using the direct path to the `ping` binary instead and check if it works. The `ping` binary complete path is that one: `/sbin/ping`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy dtruss/dtrace aren't really helpful in macOS Sierra, right - because of SID?

Comment: @JacoPretorius, it's possible to disable, and under present circumstances (when you need to see what's going on inside system-provided tools), that's probably an appropriate course of action.

Comment: @sorontar, absent `BASH_ENV`, what would be going on in the dotfiles that impacts **noninteractive** shells running as child processes? (Hmm -- I suppose there might be some pathological cases -- if one shadowed `echo` with an exported function that inserted a delay if the PID changed from its original one that would do it, but that's getting into really intentional trickery).

Comment: @vitormm, *if* that's the case, better to identify and remove the offending PATH element -- something that slows down `execlp()` by that much is going to impact more than just scripts. The operating system caches directory entries, and once a shell instance is invoked it caches PATH lookup results (one can view or clear that cache using the `hash` command in bash), so it's unusual to have a significant expense here.

Comment: @vitormm There is no ping executable involved here, just an `echo` of the string `"ping"`. Given the fact that in bash (as the question is tagged) echo is a builtin, there is very little space for delays.

Comment: @sorontar, but **neither** `.bash_profile` *or* `.bashrc` are involved in noninteractive, non-login shells. The only thing I can think of that is is a script named in `BASH_ENV`.

Comment: Ahh. Determining whether this can be reproduced from a shell whose commands are being fed to it on stdin would indeed be a useful datapoint -- and if it *can* be reproduced in that case, then determining whether disabling dotfiles is helpful is useful.

Comment: @sorontar, **however**, if the issue can only be reproduced in a shell which invokes dotfiles, then how is the OP experiencing it in the `./script.sh` case, which sources no dotfiles other than a file named in `BASH_ENV`? Or are you proposing that it's something happening in the parent process *before* it `exec`s the child? That's plausible, I suppose -- could also test it by taking the shell out of the loop and directly `exec`ing the script from a Python interpreter or such.

Comment: @codeforester `time bash -c exit` gives
real 0m0.004s
user 0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s

Comment: Could you try starting a new shell: `bash -l --norc --noprofile`. Try again the same scripts. Is the delay still present?

Comment: @sorontar I'm having the same issue, and it persists even when running under `bash --norc --noprofile -l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue on my work machine, running macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and 10.12.6, and I confirmed that @charles-duffy is right. My company's anti-malware is the problem. They are using a daemon called Confer by Carbon Black for endpoint security.

Run this command to see if the problem stops:

```
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.confer.sensor.daemon.plist
```

I think Confer is taking a fingerprint of every new program it sees and tries to compare it to a blacklist before allowing it to run. It looks like it times out after a second (trying to register the fingerprint online?), and something is making it try over and over again, yielding longer delays of integer seconds. This makes newly modified programs launch slowly, although speeds return to normal after the fingerprint has been taken.

---

## Example runs

Here's how the problem manifested on my work laptop. As time went on, sometimes the delay increased, but always by an integer number of seconds at a time. If Confer remembers the program from before, there will be no delay.

### bash scripts

```
$ bash --norc --noprofile -l  # make sure rc scripts don't interfere

bash-3.2$ echo exit > exit.sh && chmod +x exit.sh

bash-3.2$ time ./exit.sh

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s

bash-3.2$ time ./exit.sh

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.001s
```

There were no problems running commands provided to `bash -c`:

```
bash-3.2$ time bash -c exit

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.003s
```

### awk scripts

But the problem did affect awk scripts:

```
bash-3.2$ printf '%s\n' '#!/usr/bin/env awk -f' 'BEGIN { exit 0; }' > test.awk && chmod +x test.awk

bash-3.2$ time ./test.awk

real    0m4.010s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.001s

bash-3.2$ time ./test.awk

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.001s
```

### Compiled binaries

It even affected compiled C and Golang code:

```
bash-3.2$ printf '%s\n' '#include "stdio.h"' 'int main() {' 'printf("Hello, world!\n");' 'return 0;' '}' > hello.c && gcc -o hello hello.c

bash-3.2$ time ./hello
Hello, world!

real    0m4.006s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.001s

bash-3.2$ time ./hello
Hello, world!

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.001s

bash-3.2$ printf '%s\n' 'package main' 'import "fmt"' 'func main() {' 'fmt.Println("test")' '}' > test.go && go build -o test ./test.go

bash-3.2$ time ./test
test

real    0m4.018s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s

bash-3.2$ time ./test
test

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Comment: Heh -- glad to hear my WAG turned out to be accurate. As an aside, I would suggest `printf '%s\n' 'package main' 'import "fmt"' 'func main() { fmt.Println("test") }'` as a perhaps more readable way to emit multiple lines.

Comment: BTW, generally these tools can be configured to operate in a non-blocking mode where they let code run in the unknown case and make a determination after-the-fact. That might allow a more reasonable medium between performance impact and supporting corporate security measures than just unloading/disabling the daemon altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with 10.15, macOS might actually be talking to Apple every time a new script is executed. I found this in a [recent changelog for TextMate](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/v2.0.5/Applications/TextMate/about/Changes.md):

> Fixed: Delay when re-executing (bundle) commands on macOS 10.15.
>   Starting with macOS 10.15 Apple will “call home” each time a new
>   script/binary is executed, this can have a delay of more than a
>   second, depending on internet connectivity/location. The result seems
>   to be cached per inode, previously TextMate would use temporary files
>   when executing scripts or shell commands (giving them a new inode on
>   each run), it now re-uses these files to avoid the delay on repeated
>   executions.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this "call home"? Some people may not appreciate Apple spying on them so casually..